# Problemas con metodo en entity framework (linq)

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Tengo un método que es el siguiente:

```
[HttpGet("MensajesPorParticipante/{idsala}")]
    public Task<IActionResult> GetCountPorPart(int idsala)
    {
        var contador = _context.Mensajes
            .Where(s => s.SalaId == idsala)
            .GroupBy(p => new { p.EmisorId})
            .Select(r => new { r.Key.EmisorId, Total = r.Count() });

        return contador;
    }
```

Es una api de chats, en la que necesito contar la cantidad de msj que ha enviado cada participante de la sala de chat.
El problema está en en Task.

**Necesito que lo haga al estilo lista, tipo así:**

**Participante x = 10 msj**

**Participante y = 5 msj**
etc...

Pero no me sale. Me tira error en el return. Probé con un Task<List>, con ActionResult, con IEnumerable, y la verdad ya no se con qué probar xq creo no estar entendiendo EF. Hace relativamente poco que empecé con esto.

Si estoy haciendo TODO mal, adjunto la query sql que necesito tener en EF:

```
select EmisorId, count(EmisorId) as Contador
From Mensajes
where SalaId = 1
group by EmisorId
```

Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: Pallero, veo que tienes abierto 2 preguntas con la misma temática, lo que te explico se aplica a cualquiera de ellas, el error esta en que estás retornando un tipo de datos diferente al que esta definido en tu función, en este caso estás retornando un entero, cuando la función espera que retorne otro tipo de datos, si vas a retornar un entero, tienes que poner en la declaración de la función que está devuelve un entero

Comment: Ah re que no se borró la otra pregunta. @Japv acabo de cambiar el tipo de dato a Int32 pero me sigue dando el mismo error de conversión al retornar el contador.

Comment: Dime cómo lo estás poniendo cuando retorna un int

Comment: Task<Int32>, Task<Int>, de esas dos formas probé. Pero siempre me da error en el return. De todos modos, O sea, son 2 cosas que necesito: 1 es la lista de los que enviaron msj, y 2 la cantidad que envió cada uno. Tengo que pedir que me devuelva un entero o una lista? Si fuese la lista, el contador es imaginario, o sea no tengo una clase que tenga el objeto "contador de msj".

Comment: Quita el Task<> pon que devuelva int solo

Comment: Me da el error de que no se puede convertir esta parte: r.Key.EmisorId, Total = r.Count().. en entero.. Es el mismo error de siempre.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116575/discussion-between-japv-and-joel-pallero).

Comment: La tabla Mensajes, tiene varios campos el emisor del msj, y el id de la sala en la que se envió son los importantes para esta prueba. Especificando el IdSala ya se de qué sala se tiene que mostrar, y después contar cuántos msj envió cada participante. ¿Está bien hecha la consulta?